# How to replace multiple words in .docx file and save the docx file using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to change the content of the docx using python-docx library. My changes are about replacing the words. So, I have list of words `Original word list: ['ABC','XYZ']` which I need to replace with `revised word list: ['PQR', 'DEF']`. I also need to preserve the format of these words. Right now, I can save only one change. Here is my code for the reference.

```
def replace_string(filename='test.docx'):
doc = Document(filename)
list= ['ABC','XYZ']
list2 = ['PQR','DEF']
for p in doc.paragraphs:
        print(p.text)
        for i in range(0, len(list)):
            if list[i] in p.text:
                print('----!!SEARCH FOUND!!------')
                print(list[i])
                print(list2[i])
                print('\n')
                inline = p.runs
                # Loop added to work with runs (strings with same style)
                for i in range(len(inline)):
                    #print(inline[i].text)
                    if list[i] in inline[i].text:
                        print('----SEARCH FOUND!!------')
                        text = inline[i].text.replace(list[i], list2[i])
                        inline[i].text = text
                        print(inline[i].text)
        doc.save('dest1.docx')
return 1

replace_string()
```

Original content of test.docx file:

`ABC
XYZ`

Revised content or saved content of dest1.docx file:

`PQR
XYZ`

How can I save all the replacements? The list of word may increase and its size is not fix.

Comment: Here I got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following code works for me. This preserve the format as well. Hope this will help others.

```
def replace_string1(filename='test.docx'):
doc = Document(filename)
list= ['ABC','XYZ']
list2 = ['PQR','DEF']
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    inline = p.runs
    for j in range(0,len(inline)):
        for i in range(0, len(list)):
            inline[j].text = inline[j].text.replace(list[i], list2[i])
            print(p.text)
            print(inline[j].text)
doc.save('dest1.docx')
return 1
```

Comment: This won't help anyone if you don't explain *what* was wrong and what's different in this code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `inline[i].text = text` creating the problem  as it replace the word with content of paragraph and after removing this line, code ran the way I wanted

Comment: Update the answer explaining what this does. This answer won't help anyone if they have to compare it to the original just to find out what's different. Did you change the loops for example? Were the indices mixed up? Something else?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `inline[i].text = text`. Your current code is *identical*. `inline[j].text.replace(list[i], list2[i])` produces a value. Whether that's stored in a variable named `text` or remains a temporary value, it's still assigned to `inline[j].text`.

Comment: It looks like the only thing that changed was the loop variable. You were using the *same* loop variable for both the words and runs loops, which means you were trying to replace the wrong words. The significant change in the answer is that each loop now uses a different loop variable

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a version of JT28's solution, using a dictionary to replace the text (instead of two lists) - this lets me generate paired find, replace items more simply. Key is what I'm looking for, and v is what is in the new substring. The function allows replacement in one paragraph or all paragraphs, depending on whether the caller is iterating (or not) over doc.paragraphs.

```
# NEW FUNCTION:
def replacer(p, replace_dict):
    inline = p.runs  # Specify the list being used
    for j in range(0, len(inline)):

        # Iterate over the dictionary
        for k, v in replace_dict.items():
            if k in inline[j].text:
                inline[j].text = inline[j].text.replace(k, v)
    return p

# Replace Paragraphs
doc = Document(filename)  # Get the file
dict = {'ABC':'PQR', 'XYZ':'DEF'}  # Build the dict
for p in doc.paragraphs:  # If needed, iter over paragraphs
    p = replacer(p, dict)  # Call the new replacer function
```